# SNMP : snmpbulkget - non-repeaters and max-repetitions

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

What does non-repeaters and max-repetitions states in snmpbulkget:

If I run below command:

```
 ./snmpbulkget -v2c -Cn1 -Cr11 -c public 217.169.128.14:161 sysDescr ifTable
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: loopback.
IF-MIB::ifIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
IF-MIB::ifIndex.2 = INTEGER: 2
IF-MIB::ifIndex.3 = INTEGER: 3
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: loopback
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: loopback1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: loopback2
IF-MIB::ifType.1 = INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)
IF-MIB::ifType.2 = INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)
IF-MIB::ifType.3 = INTEGER: ethernetCsmacd(6)
```

Which are the Oids values that agent (running at 217.169.128.14:161) should return?

Comment: As far as I know, GETBULK messages were introduced in snmp V2 and not available in V1.

Comment: Thanks - changed v1 to v2c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, GETBULK requests were added with version 2 of SNMP.
You therefore should state `-v2c` instead of `-v1`.

In your example you ask for a single non-repeater (`-Cn1`).
I.e., a single get-next for `sysDescr` which will return `sysDescr.0`.

Furthermore, you're asking for the first 11 nodes within the `ifTable` (`-Cr11`).
Depending on your type of equipment, it'll return probably the first 11 `ifIndex` nodes.

**UPDATE**
Here below the result of a real device I interrogated for `ipAddrTable` that actually has 3 rows (I masked the values for obvious reasons):

**`snmpbulkget -v2c -Cn1 -Cr11 -c xxxxxx a.b.c.d sysDescr ipAddrTable`**

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: XXXXXXXXX
IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.w.x.y.z = IpAddress: w.x.y.z
IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.a.b.c.d = IpAddress: a.b.c.d
IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.127.0.0.1 = IpAddress: 127.0.0.1
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.w.x.y.z = INTEGER: 6291456
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.a.b.c.d = INTEGER: 8388668
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.127.0.0.1 = INTEGER: 2097152
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.w.x.y.z = IpAddress: 255.255.255.0
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.a.b.c.d = IpAddress: 255.255.255.0
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.127.0.0.1 = IpAddress: 255.0.0.0
IP-MIB::ipAdEntBcastAddr.w.x.y.z = INTEGER: 1
IP-MIB::ipAdEntBcastAddr.a.b.c.d = INTEGER: 1
```

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't getnext of sysDesc return the next OID - sysObjectID I mean GetNext on .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 should return .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2?

Comment: Can you please explain "first 11 ifIndex nodes" does it means that 11 times getnext on IfTable would be performed but as results (as updated in question) I see only 9 indexed values

Comment: The object successive to sysDescr (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) is the instance of that node. I.e 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0

Comment: Thanks - I get the point but what about the 9 indexed values returned by agent - should it not return total 11 indexed values?

Comment: The agent should return 11 nodes. If the ifTable has only 3 rows (as your question suggests), it should also return the first 2 rows of ifMtu.